# Как спарсить текст с сайта Python?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

В общем, столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно спарсить место положение с сайта "https://2ip.ru/"
Мне нужно получить >Россия, Уфа< при помощи библиотек beautiful-soup и requests. Я новичок в парсинге, поэтому это может быть глупый вопрос. Буду рад любой помощи.

[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала Вам нужно получить HTML-код страницы. Это Вы можете сделать с помощью библиотеки [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). Содержимое ответа будет находиться в атрибуте [`text`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content).

Затем Вы должны распарсить HTML-код с помощью [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Обратите внимание, что код может быть невалидный. Но `bs4` сделает всё возможное, чтобы Вы могли с ним хоть как-то работать. Вы можете посмотреть код после парсинга, просто напечатав его на экран.

Найти конкретный элемент Вы можете несколькими способами. Например, с помощью [CSS-селекторов](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). За это отвечает метод `select`.

***Пример:***

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://2ip.ru/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

div = soup.select('div[class="value value-country"]')[0]
location = div.text.strip()
print(location)
```

***stdout:***

```
Россия, Уфа
```

Comment: Спасибо, огромное!